Error on Xcode: Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'NavigationLink<VocabularyPackView, VocabListView>' conform to 'TableRowContent'
Not sure how to tackle this. I am making a vocabulary app and am very new to coding. I have made sure the NavigationLink and its contents are correctly set up as well. Getting the error message at the line:
NavigationLink(destination: VocabListView(pack: vocabPack)) {

import SwiftUI

struct LiteratureTextView: View {
    let text: LiteratureText
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(text.subPacks) { pack in
                switch pack {
                case .vocabulary(let vocabPack):
                    NavigationLink(destination: VocabListView(pack: vocabPack)) { 
                        VocabularyPackView(pack: vocabPack)
                    }
                case .quotes(let quotePack):
                    if quotePack.name == "First Letters" {
                        NavigationLink(destination: FirstLettersListView(pack: quotePack)) {
                            VocabularyPackView(pack: quotePack)
                        }
                    } else {
                        NavigationLink(destination: QuotesListView(pack: quotePack)) {
                            VocabularyPackView(pack: quotePack)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(text.name)
    }
}

Made sure that some identifiers are Identifiable

The key is that each entry in your View List has to derive from TableRowContent, but NavigationLink doesn't.  You probably just need to wrap those in a TableRowContent.

Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code.
In particular, show the code for your various structs, eg LiteratureText
and subPacks. Also show whether the code is inside a Table and where you declare
the required NavigationStack.
